# UITextField within UITableViewCell

Tags: ios

In my application I am creating `UITextField` within `UITableViewCell` so that user can fill some information. This is my code:

```
if (![cell.contentView viewWithTag:10])
{
    UITextField *textField=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30)];
    [textField setTag:10];
    [textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];  
}
```

I am doing this so that I create that `UITextField` only once for each cell so that the textFields don't overlap... but a problem happened for example when the user writes in the textfields:

```
row 0 -> 0
row 1 -> 1
row 2 -> 2
row 3 -> 3
row 4 -> 4
```

And so on, if you have number of rows more than 10 and you started to scroll I can notice that the cells exchange there indices randomly so i can get something like:

```
row 0 -> 3
row 1 -> 1
row 2 -> 2
row 3 -> 0
row 4 -> 4
```

in the UITextField.text 
how to make something or a trick like fixed position for each cell?

Comment: When you have to scroll the table, cells get re-used and put in different places.  If you have fixed data, you can use a static table (in a storyboard) or (more appropriately) store the data immediately after it is entered and save it in your data source for the appropriate row that it is in at the time they finish editing.

Comment: @lnafziger the data is Dynamic , how you suggest to store data and display it in the correct or responding textField when the user scrolls ,,thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: It's the way TableViews work.  You have provide your own array to track cell contents that get scrolled off the screen.  Study the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This can look as a 'bad' decision, but I would strongly recommend you Not to use UITableView with UITextFields unless you have like 40 textfields, because of the following reasons:

- It lags the way you described, because NSIndexPath is calculated on
  the go and the text that user filled in the textfields would jump
  around the table when you scroll.
- You will have a mess when implementing logics to get out text from
  the textfields.
- You will have to implement a big piece of code to implement "scroll
  table up and down" animation to let user navigate through textfields,
  i.e in `textFieldDidBeginEditing`

If you still want to use tableview, i would recommend you to set some key to each of your UITextFields, and create a datasource (like `NSDictionary`) that binds this key to a certain text value that you can get from it any time.

Then you will probably have an ugly piece of code like this:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldValueChanged:(UITextField *)sender
{
    MyTableCell *cell = (MyTableCell*)sender.superview.superview;
    [self.formDataSource setObject:cell.formTextField.text forKey:cell.contentKey];
}
```

Then when you need you can enumerate through formDataSource `allValues` property.

Comment: It's really not that hard, done properly. A few `enum`s and using a `nil` `reuseIdentifier` makes it quite easy; a few of the methods can get large (especially some `switch`es), but it's not that difficult and looks better than trying to handle it manually.

Comment: Storyboards won't allow nil reuseIdentifier, and as for me it seems more like a hack. As an alternative tags can be used, but the key-valued datasource is a must.

Comment: Storyboards let you set up static tables to do the same thing for you, if he's using storyboards he's doing it wrong and the question is moot. Some might consider it a slight hack, but the cell recycling is only meant to reduce memory consumption in arbitrarily large data sets. Having a small, fixed number of rows increases memory usage trivially, if at all.

Comment: it's also used to make the tableview animation faster without creating tonns of object on the go. By using nil reuseIdentifier you mean just not using dequeReusableCell: method or something else? Can you give an example of what you are proposing as I did not find any references to your hack

Comment: ... Exactly what I said. `[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:foo resourceIdentifier:nil]`. And if anything, the `nil` identifier is faster because all the cells are pre-made, ready to go without any alteration.

Comment: And like I said, it's only better with a fixed number of rows small enough to not add a noticeable memory footprint

Comment: so resourceIdentifier:nil makes his problem go away always returning correct cell or how?

Comment: ["reuseIdentifier:
A string used to identify the cell object if it is to be reused for drawing multiple rows of a table view. Pass nil if the cell object is not to be reused."](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938) I.e. initializing a cell with a RID of `nil` keeps it out of the reuse pool.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an abbreviated sample of how I do this in one of my view controllers:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell
        = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AttributeCellIdentifier];
    NSString *propertyName = @"...";
    NSString *className = @"...";
    UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];

    UITextField* textField = (UITextField*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];

    textField.text = [self stringForAttribute:propertyName];
    label.text = propertyName;

    return cell;
}
```

**tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:** is part of the **UITableViewDataSource** protocol.  It gets called whenever the table view needs to scroll new cells into view.  Since it is recycling cells that have scrolled out of view automatically, you need to reset the state of the cell in this method based on the values in your model.

You may also find it useful to know you can configure your custom cell in Interface Builder, in your Storyboard.  Just be sure to set an appropriate reuse identifier so that your controller will always be able to supply the right type of cell.